# How to require and use a ES6 class in a next.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, es6-class

I am working on a next.js app and I would like to move the code that interact with the database out of the api. I created a class that would be my manager:

```
class UserManager
{

    async findUser(email) {
        //some code
        return user;
    }

    async updateUser(user, reqBody) {
        //some other code
        //return something
    }
}
module.exports = UserManager;
```

and I am trying to use this class from my api

```
const UserManager = require('../../manager/UserManager');


export default async (req, res) => {
    const email = session.user.email;
    let UserManager = new UserManager();
    const user = await UserManager.findUser(email);
}
```

and I am getting this error

```
| ReferenceError: Cannot access 'UserManager1' before initialization
|   10 |     }
|   11 |     const email = session.user.email;
| > 12 |     let UserManager = new UserManager();
|      |                      ^
```

what's wrong with this approach? Am I requiring the class in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with modules or `requre`. Just variables and scope.

You have two variables named `UserManager`.

One is a `const` and is scoped to the module and contains the class.

The other is a `let` is is scoped to the exported arrow function; it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `const`.

You’re trying to read the `const` inside the function but it is shadowed by the `let`. Since you are trying to read the `const` *first* (to call a function to get the value to assign to the `let`) you get an error because the rules of JS say that you’re reading the `let` (not the `const` you want).

**Change the variable name you use for the `let`**.

Idiomatic JS reserves variable names starting with a capital letter for classes and constructor functions (and React.js adds components to that list). The `let` variable is being assigned an *instance* of a class, not the class itself, so its name shouldn’t start with a capital letter.

```
let userManager = new UserManager();
```

---

I recommend  using the eslint [`no-shadow` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow) to alert you when you make this error.

---

Aside: Your class doesn’t appear to track any internal state, it is just used to create an object to group some methods together (none of which even make use of `this`). It would probably be better off as a plain object rather than a class.